# Letting the camera move along different paths

Tags: animation, objects

**What I want:**

I have a model of a room with several objects in it. I want to see the objects in the room from several camera positions on three of the four walls. Basically, I want to let my camera follow predefined paths along these walls.

**What I did:**

I could not figure out how to make a path looking like an open rectangle, so I decided to create three different paths, one for each of the three walls. I managed to let my camera follow one of the paths nicely. However, I do not manage to let my camera jump to the next path/wall once its done with the previous one. According to this thread http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?204414-Follow-one-path-after-another-in-Blender-2-5 it should work with object constraints and the influence value, but since the blender file given there is not available anymore, I can't figure out how to do it. So, how would you animate the camera for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, I have seen this question and its answers but ran into problems when using object constraints, cmp.: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13908/difference-between-ctrlp-follow-path-and-add-object-constraint. Also, I do not really know how to animate the influences. But you are right, the problem is similar, even though here I was also hoping to learn if there is a better way to model an open rectangle.

Comment: I think you could do with being more specific in your question then. Is your question 'How do I animate constraint influences?', 'How do I use the follow path constraint?' or 'How do I create an open rectangle?' (though I don't know what 'open rectangle' means).

Comment: Well, for 'How do I use the follow path constraint?' I added the other question. Maybe you are right and splitting the question into more subquestions would be better, but then context is lost. To understand what I mean by 'open rectangle' you need to imagine the situation. Imagine a room with 90° angles and I want to position the camera on three of the foor walls, for now always on the same height. The path to describe this would look like a rectangle with one side missing ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking multiple separate questions, which should be asked individually.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use multiple curves:

1. Add a circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Curve > Circle*)
2. Switch to edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and set the handles to vector (<kbd>V</kbd>*> Vector*)
3. Delete one segment by selecting two of the control vertices on one side and pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd>*> Segments*.

[image]

To align the curve to the axes, rotate it 45° on the Z (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> `45`).

Answer (score 2):

### Here is how you can make a rectangular path:

1. add a new bezier curve circle.
2. select all the points and hit <kbd>V</kbd>

   [image]
3. rotate it 45 degrees.

Now you have a square.

Heres how you can make it align with corners in you room:

1. change the snapping mode to vertex
   [image]
2. While holding down Ctrl, move your vertices to the top corners of the wall.
3. adjust to vertical potion of the path as you wish.
4. To open the path un-check cyclic in the path options.

   ### Here is how you can switch paths:
5. Add your two paths. next select your object that you want to follow the path and add a follow path constraint.
6. Go into the paths setting and set the frames to the right amount, also copy that value.
7. Select your curve and press animate path
8. now in your time line, move to the last frame of the path value, the value you just copied.
9. In the follow path constraint set the influence to 1, and add a key frame.
10. Go to the next frame, set the influence to 1, and add anther a key frame.
11. add you next path.
12. Repeat steps 1 through 4 on this new path.
13. Go to the the frame that the other path was at influence one, and set a key on the influence (0) on the new constraint.
14. move to the next frame and set the influence to one. Key it.

Done!

Comment: Nice! Thanks :) If you add how to "open" the rectangle, I will accept yours as an answer since you also described how to switch paths.

Comment: While in edit mode of a curve Alt-C will turn on/off cyclic, which joins the first and last curve points. This property can be found under Active spline->Cyclic in the curve properties.

Comment: @sambler - nice!

Comment: @user1809923 Ideally we want to keep to one specific question per post. This helps keep questions to more widely useful operations that are more likely help other users coming from search engines. Could you split your question into separate posts, e.g. as Ray Mairlot [suggested](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/letting-the-camera-move-along-different-paths/13940#comment18839_13910)? Links to related posts can be added to provide context.