# Light following displaced object

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, lighting

I have the following objects:

- a bezier curve
- an object, with a Curve modifier targeting the bezier curve. The object is not at (0,0,0) for itself - it has a translation.
- a light

What I'd like to do is have the light somehow follow the displaced object. Think a car driving along a curve and the light being the car's headlights. However, there don't seem to be any modifiers for a light.
On the other hand, I tried the constraints (Copy Location, Child Of, Follow Path) to see if those could fix my issue, but to no avail. I even tried instancing the lights on (a duplicate of) the relevant vertices on the mesh.

How do I fix this, guys?

Here's a screenshot of what happens to the light when I simply make it a child (with Ctrl-P) of the object.
[image: failed attempt]

Comment: Parent light to mesh with modifier disabled.

Comment: @vklidu with that make the light follow the modified mesh when I re-enable the modifier?

Comment: You should probably share your simplified blend (car represented as a cube or so) ... there is more ways to let object follow curve also there is more options to parent light - you can parent to object's origin that fits to car model, but you can also parent to vertex or three vertices ... ect

Answer (score 0):

- Parent *Light* object to *Mesh* object.
- **Origin** of *Curve* object (path) and *Mesh* (car) has to be at the same location.
- Add **Follow Path** constraint to your Mesh, select *Target*, press Animate Path, enable *Follow Curve*

[image]

[image]

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13915/2214