# Problems with Follow Path

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints

When I use the function *Follow Path* with any object it separates a lot by marking a blue dashed line and I have to use the command <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd> to get into path. Does anyone know why this happens to me?

When I directly use the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> > *Follow Path* I don't have this problem.
I use version 3.1.2

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13908/difference-between-ctrl-p-follow-path-and-add-object-constraint) post, I think it will answer you questions. Clicking "Follow Path" is not the same as adding a Follow Path constraint. You probably want to be clicking "Path Constraint" in the Ctrl+P menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe 2 ways to follow path:

- If you parent the object to the curve with the *Follow Path* option, the object will begin its animation at the position it was when you parented
- If you use the *Follow Path* constraint, the first vertex of the curve will be like the new world center of the object, so the object will be as far from this vertex as it is from the center of the scene when you've given it the constraint. So if you want the object to be at the same location as the first vertex you need to bring back the object at the center of the scene with an <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and it will jump at the vertex position.

Comment: Thanks a lot! already all fixed.