# Uncontrollable Offset with Follow Path

Tags: bones, bezier-curves, constraints, path, bone.constraints

When I set the target of the Follow-Path Constraint my object moves to some other position which I cant control and dont want. How can I fix this?
I think it has something to do with the blue dashed line (Relationship Line?) It seems to be relative to World origin.
[image: Cube at default position, no target set]
[image: Cube changed position, after target set]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260983/problems-with-follow-path?rq=1

Comment: to add to Hadriscus answer, the object also needs to be at the center of the scene if you want it to stick to the beginning of your curve, so once its origin is at it center, put the object at the center of the scene with an Alt G

Answer (score 1):

Constraints operate on object transforms, regardless of the geometry they contain. It appears the cube mesh has moved from its origin, you probably moved it away while in edit mode. To recenter it, you can select the object (in object mode), shift+S -> cursor to selected, then enter edit mode, select all, and shift+S -> selection to cursor (offset).